# Perl regular expression - search and replace

Tags: regex, perl

I can't get my head around perl search and replace in a string, or regular expressions.  Can someone help, please?

I've got a file that contains HTML and I want to change the class of certain items if they a present in given set (in this case a hash table or validated fields that failed validation).  So I've got, for example, the following:

```
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" class="inputnormal" value="Good">
```

and I want to change the "inputnormal" class to the value "inputpink".  What I'm trying to do is make it so that I match the whole string nomatter in which order the properties appear, so that, for example, the following will also match:

```
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" value="Good" class="inputnormal">
```

This is because Dreamweaver will sometimes mess around with the order of properties in the HTML during editing, so I can't rely on fixed positions for them.

So I end up with something that doesn't work, such as:

```
foreach $key ( keys %FAILED ) { 
    $infile =~ s/<input type="radio" name="$key" value="$VALUES{$key}" class="([a-zA-Z]+)"/$1inputpink"/gi;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks.

Edit:  ok, this kind-of works, assuming the properties inside the tags don't move around:

```
foreach $key ( keys %FAILED ) {
    $infile =~ s/(<.{4,10}\ type="radio" name="$key".{1,60}class=")([a-zA-Z]+)"/$1inputpink"/gi;
}
```

That will have to do for now!  Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Regular expressions are *really* bad at these kind of tasks. I would recommend some kind of HTML parser for this. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Perl to suggest one.

Comment: I don't have that option, unfortunately.  I have only really basic hosting here (well, the company does!) and only Perl 6 is available.  No fancy add-on modules either.  Luckily we can count the number of people hitting this script on one hand, per week, so for performance we're not really going to be in trouble :p.

Comment: @Robinson: you mean you can't install any perl module on your machine? Checks if you have perhaps [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.68/Parser.pm) or [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.1/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm). Maybe these modules are pre-installed, and you can use them to parse HTML without using regex, which, as pointed out in the other comments, is not a good idea.

Comment: Not on my machine Marco, it's on the hosting space we use, which is hideously basic.  I realise that I'm not using the right tool for the job by any stretch; only that around once a year I have to modify something here and because I don't really retain the knowledge I gain over the few days I'm working on it, I have to re-learn Perl every year!

Comment: @Robinson: I understand. However, check on the machine on the hosting space if one of those two modules is already installed. You can do that from the command prompt (assuming you can open a prompt on your remote machine, maybe ssh): do `perl -MHTML::Parser`: if the module is installed you don't get any error message, and you exit perl interpreter with `CTRL+C`. Same thing for the other module `perl -MHTML::TreeBuilder`.

Comment: I can ftp to the hosting space, that's about it.  I can't open a command prompt.  The only way to do it would be to see if I can actually use it in a script.  Debugging is trial and error (try until you no longer get the server "something went wrong" page returned).  Yes, all in all it's a pretty awful developer experience.

Comment: @Robinson: really awful situation :( OK, maybe you can try and see if one of those module is available by including it in one of your script. If you don't get the error message, then it's worth investing some time in using the module to parse your HTML. If you get the error message ... you're in trouble :(

Comment: Without a module, a Perl programmer cannot do anything else?

Comment: @Robinson: Read this and see if any of the options help: http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/

Comment: Since you say your on basic hosting I assume you can run a CGI. You can check for installed modules using a script like `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"; eval { print "Checking for HTML::Parser\n"; require HTML::Parser; print "Found HTML::Parser\n"; }; eval { print "Checking for HTML::TreeBuilder\n"; require HTML::TreeBuilder; print "Found HTML::TreeBuilder\n"; };` Add a suitable `#!` line etc.

Comment: Interesting.  With that script I got the following:  "Checking for HTML::Parser
Found HTML::Parser
Checking for HTML::TreeBuilder", i.e. got Parser, but haven't got TreeBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching the entire input tag, I recommend matching the class part. This regex should work I think....

```
my $htmlLine = "<input name=\"RMAProcess\" type=\"radio\" class=\"inputnormal\" value=\"Good\">";
$htmlline =~s/class="inputnormal"/class="inputpink"/i;
```

Comment: That would work, yes.  I will mark this as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an HTML parser to parse HTML.  I use [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~jfearn/HTML-Tree-4.1/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice,

```
$ cat file
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" class="inputnormal" value="Good">
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" value="Good" class="inputnormal">

$ ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/(.*class=")(.[^"]*)(".*)/, "\\1inputpink\\3"  ) ' file
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" class="inputpink" value="Good">
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" value="Good" class="inputpink">
```

its just substitution with back references, so the regex could be used in a Perl context as well...

If you need to make sure there is `name="", type="", value=""`, then use `if` eg

```
ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/(.*class=")(.[^"]*)(".*)/, "\\1inputpink\\3"  ) if /name=/&&/type=/&&/value=/' file
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're just matching on class="x" here.  I want to match on name="x" type="y" value="z" and then replace the class="p" value within the angle brackets.  Sorry I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to do this in two steps:

1. Split the line into attributes and check if "name=X" and "type=y",  by creating a hash on attributes or running several reg.exps.
2. If you then want to change the line, you can just replace class with a simple reg.exp

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install any module, you can try something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;


my %FAILED = (RMAProcess => 'Good');

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    foreach my $key ( keys %FAILED ) { 
        if ($line =~ /type="radio"/ && $line =~ /name="$key"/ && $line =~/value="$FAILED{$key}"/) {
            $line =~ s/class="([a-zA-Z]+)"/class="inputpink"/;
        }
    }
    say $line;
}

__DATA__
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" class="inputnormal" value="Good">
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" value="Good" class="inputnormal">
```

**output:**

```
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" class="inputpink" value="Good">
<input name="RMAProcess" type="radio" value="Good" class="inputpink">
```